# Multicolumns the same length

Tags: multicolumn

When running this program, I can not get the columns of equal length. Please advise how this can be accomplished.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{c|c} 
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\bf Some Ordered Pairs}} \\ \hline 
 x & y \\ \hline 
 2 & 4 \\ \hline 
 5 & 25 \\ \hline 
 7 & 49  \\ \hline 
 12 & 144 \\ \hline 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{10ex}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{10ex}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Some Ordered Pairs}} \\ \hline
x & y      \\ \hline
2 & 4      \\ \hline
5 & 25     \\ \hline
7 & 49     \\ \hline
12 & 144   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

alternative solution is use of `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.35\linewidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Some Ordered Pairs}} \\ \hline
x & y      \\ \hline
2 & 4      \\ \hline
5 & 25     \\ \hline
7 & 49     \\ \hline
12 & 144   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

in both cases you need to estimate the needed width of table. in the first case use its half to determine width of columns, in the second columns width is automatically calculated from table width.

Comment: That does it. Thanks. I think I didn't need to add the array package in the first example.

Comment: @MathScholar, try yourself. you will see, that it is needed.